# Question mark in a sentence that does not start with WH

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I needed to ask someone why something was redirected to a different team. I want to use 'Not sure' along with my question to leave a bit of skepticism. My question is,can we use the question  mark if we don't start our question with Do, Does, or Wh questions?

Not sure why this was redirected to EBOSS team?.

Also should this question be rephrased as "Not sure why was this redirected to EBOSS team"?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your question needs more clarity

Comment: I have modified my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a casual style, so it doesn't really matter.

It's not a full sentence, it suggests:

> *I am *not sure....

And that is syntactically a statement. As it is syntactically a statement you write "..why this was..". But there is an implication of a question

> I am not sure why... *Can you tell me*?

The writer was thinking a question, and that is probably why they used a question mark. In formal writing you would need to write a full sentence and you wouldn't use a question mark. In casual style, people sometimes put question marks when the question is only implied.